# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2493 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that this question may be asked quite often but I have been trying to find the issue with this left join.  I have searched around and tried a few different things but I am still having trouble identifying what is wrong with it.

```
left join (
    SELECT
        MAX(e.date) as MaxDate
        ,e.patientID
    FROM
        labdata ld
        inner join enc e on e.encounterID = ld.EncounterId
            and e.deleteFlag = 0
            and ld.deleteFlag = 0
            and ld.futureflag = 0
            and ld.cancelled = 0
            and ld.received = 1
        inner join @patients t on t.patientID = e.patientID
        inner join structsocialhistory SSH on SSH.encounterId = e.encounterID
        INNER JOIN (structdatadetail SDD ON SSH.catid = SDD.catid      
                AND     SSH.itemid = SDD.itemid 
                AND   SSH.detailid = SDD.id)
        WHERE SSH.catid  = 10619
        AND SSH.itemid = 318681 
        AND SSH.detailID = 49 AND SSH.ValueID =82
        OR SSH.detailID = 51 AND SSH.ValueID IN(88,89,145)
        AND SSH.detailID IN(52,53,98,99,100,101,106,107,108,109) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SSH.Value) = 'Yes'

    GROUP BY
        e.patientID
) SmokeCounselMaxDate on SmokeCounselMaxDate.patientid = u.uid
```

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the brackets from this bit:

```
INNER JOIN (structdatadetail SDD ON SSH.catid = SDD.catid      
            AND     SSH.itemid = SDD.itemid 
            AND   SSH.detailid = SDD.id)
```

Comment: After doing so I am getting an error when trying to define the variable in the select statement.

The multi-part identifier "SmokeCounselMaxDate.MaxDate" could not be bound.

Comment: The query you posted doesn't contain `SmokeCounselMaxDate.MaxDate`, and the SQL you posted is incomplete. This question is over (it's been answered), please post the full query and the current error(s) you're getting as an entirely new question. Please avoid the temptation to "scope creep" a question, where it starts off asking about one thing, then shifts to another and another..

Answer (score -1):

Check this I removed the brackets at table structdatadetail

left join (
    SELECT
        MAX(e.date) as MaxDate
        ,e.patientID
    FROM
        labdata ld
        inner join enc e on e.encounterID = ld.EncounterId
            and e.deleteFlag = 0
            and ld.deleteFlag = 0
            and ld.futureflag = 0
            and ld.cancelled = 0
            and ld.received = 1
        inner join @patients t on t.patientID = e.patientID
        inner join structsocialhistory SSH on SSH.encounterId = e.encounterID
        INNER JOIN structdatadetail SDD ON SSH.catid = SDD.catid
                AND     SSH.itemid = SDD.itemid 
                AND   SSH.detailid = SDD.id
        WHERE SSH.catid  = 10619
        AND SSH.itemid = 318681 
        AND SSH.detailID = 49 AND SSH.ValueID =82
        OR SSH.detailID = 51 AND SSH.ValueID IN(88,89,145)
        AND SSH.detailID IN(52,53,98,99,100,101,106,107,108,109) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SSH.Value) = 'Yes'

```
GROUP BY
    e.patientID
```

) SmokeCounselMaxDate on SmokeCounselMaxDate.patientid = u.uid

Comment: After doing so I am getting an error when trying to define the variable in the select statement. The multi-part identifier "SmokeCounselMaxDate.MaxDate" could not be bound.